# can i import vue2-daterange-picker package without npm install?

Tags: vuejs2, vue2-daterange-picker

I am currently working on a project that does not accept the installation of packages, and i want to work with vue2-daterange-picker. here is my skelton :

@extends('layout')
@section('css')

```
<style>

</style>
```

@endsection
@section('content')

```
<date-range-picker
       v-model="dateRange"
       :date-format="dateFormat"
    ></date-range-picker>


<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: function () {
            return {
                api: api_url,
            }
        },
        components: { 

        },
        computed: {
            
        },
        mounted: function () {

        },
        created: function () {

        },
        methods: {

        },
        watch: {

        },
    });
</script>
```

@endsection

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library CDN files

just insert the below HTML codes inside the header tag

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue2-daterange-picker@0.6.8/dist/vue2-daterange-picker.umd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue2-daterange-picker@0.6.8/dist/vue2-daterange-picker.min.css">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i used the library CDN files but i must use <date-range-picker> tag in my html so it needs to be imported in components, in this case i don't know how can i do it?

Comment: Can you inject those CDN tags into index.html file? if you can't, there is no way you can import it